# EntityFramework error o no guarda cambios

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estoy teniendo problemas para guardar una entidad en mi contexto EF6, lo he intentado de varias formas y en 1 no da error pero no guarda, la otra da error.

```
var RegistroProducto = new tblProductos()
        {
            Estado = true,
            FechaInsercion = FechaRegistro,
            SKU = NoIdentificacion,
            Referencia = Referencia,
        };

        Tienda.tblProductos.Add(RegistroProducto);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Este código no da error pero no guarda ningún cambio en la db.

```
var RegistroProducto = new tblProductos()
        {
            tblTienda = Tienda,
            Estado = true,
            FechaInsercion = FechaRegistro,
            SKU = NoIdentificacion,
            Referencia = Referencia,               
        };

        dbContext.tblProductos.Add(RegistroProducto);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Este código da el siguiente error: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Alguna idea?

Comment: Archer_A, Que enfoque de Entity Framework estas usando?, ese metodo esta en tu capa de persistencia?

Comment: @PedroÁvila La entidad Tienda la obtengo cuando el usuario entra al sistema, esto para obtener toda la información relacionada con la Tienda, productos existentes, sucursales, etc, posteriormente quiero agregarle un Producto a esa tienda con el código de arriba y ahí viene el error, la entidad Tienda, es por que existen muchas tiendas en el mismo sistema

Comment: Si quieres agregar productos a un inventario, tienes que saber primero que Sucursal(Tienda) es. Revisa en tu estructura de datos, en tu tabla que informacion te pide, para que envies la información correcta.

Comment: @PedroÁvila Si es correcto, y así lo tengo, como comento, lo intente hacer de 2 maneras, la opción 1 al crear la entidad le defino a la tienda que pertenece tblTienda = Tienda, en la opción 2, lo asigno a la tienda Tienda.tblProductos.Add(RegistroProducto);

Comment: ¿Que es Tienda? es algún código? como 1, 2, 3.... ó 001, 002, 003?

Answer (score 1):

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Este error indica que tienes un problema con el manejo de tus contextos.  Mas precisamente, quiere decir que tienes una entidad que aun está "attached" a un context, pero ahora estás tratando de usar esa misma entidad con un contexto diferente.

Tristemente, no has compartido suficiente código para que realmente sea [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sin embargo, según lo que puedo ver, es muy probable que el culpable es la entidad `Tienda`.

La entidad `Tienda` aun debe estar "attached" o ligada a un contexto diferente al contexto `dbContext`, por lo que no puedes usarlo con `dbContext`.

Para ilustrar el problema, prueba este código simplificado (ajústalo a los verdaderos nombres de tus clases):

```
// cambia "TuDbContext" al nombre de tu DbContext.
using (var ctx1 = new TuDbContext())
{
    // Reemplaza esta sentencia con la que usas para cargar la instancia "Tienda".
    var Tienda = ctx1.tblTiendas.Where(t => t.Id == 123).Single();

    using(var ctx2 = new TuDbContext())
    {
        var RegistroProducto = new tblProductos()
        {
            tblTienda = Tienda,
            Estado = true,
            FechaInsercion = FechaRegistro,
            SKU = NoIdentificacion,
            Referencia = Referencia,              
        };

        ctx2.tblProductos.Add(RegistroProducto); // ¡ERROR!
    }
}
```

Si ejecutas este ejemplo, verás que resultará en el mismo error tuyo en la sentencia siguiente:

```
ctx2.tblProductos.Add(RegistroProducto);
```

¿Por qué? Porque está tratando de agregar `Tienda` al contexto `ctx2`, pero `Tienda` aun pertenece al contexto `ctx1`.

No estoy seguro de cual es la solución mas adecuada para tu situación, porque no puedo ver tu código completo. Pero me parece muy raro que estés manejando múltiples instancias de tu contexto simultáneamente.

Puede que la solución sea simplemente de asegurarte que el contexto que cargó la variable `Tienda` esté cerrada para cuando uses la variable para agregar el nuevo producto. O tal vez es cuestión de asegurarte que siempre estés usando el mismo contexto. Pero por lo menos, si entiendes la causa, de seguro encontrarás la mejor manera de corregir el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Proveedor entity)
    {
        using (PosContext Context = new PosContext())
        {

                    Context.Proveedores.Add(entity);
                    Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```